# CSS3 Unordered List Floating Issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is possibly an easy to answer question, but I can't figure out a solution.

I have two `ul` in my html. I also set each `li` to `float:left` in my css. The reason I did that is because I have a four column grid and I needed to layout the list items.

If a list don't take the full width of my grid, the following list begins at the same line.

[image]

*The Items of one list should stay inline, while the whole lists should display below each other.*

=> https://jsfiddle.net/gugubaight/93xv9tgt/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="tools">
    <li>
      <img>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="tools">
    <li>
      <img>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.wrapper {
      width: 1440px;
      max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul#tools {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    li {
        padding: .25rem .25rem 3rem;
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        -webkit-animation: appear .5s ease-in;
        animation: appear .5s ease-in;
        img {
            width: 350px;
            max-width: 350px;
            height: 225px;
            max-height: 225px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
    }
}
```

I am grateful for each help!

Comment: it because you use same ID for both ul .. ID's r always need to be unique

Comment: @Mostafa Baezid Ha. I am tired, can't believe I missed that. That does not fix the problem though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the h1 tag creating the problem. 
Update: here is the live fiddle just the structure I made for you. 
just remove float: left from li and add into your ul class or id

{display: inline-flex;}

its better you make id to class or if you want id then make deference like tools1 and tools2 .. I for now use class

```
.wrapper {
      width: 1440px;
      max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tools {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-flex;
  li {
    padding: .25rem .25rem 3rem;
    width: 25%;

    -webkit-animation: appear .5s ease-in;
    animation: appear .5s ease-in;
    img {
      width: 350px;
      max-width: 350px;
      height: 225px;
      max-height: 225px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

  }

}
ul li >  .footer{
      float:right ;
    }

<div class='wrapper'>
 <h1>Recent Tools by my favorite Developers</h1>
 <ul class='tools'>
  <li>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
    <h2>test  </h2>
  <p>test test test</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i>test</p>
  <p> <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>test</p>
  <span class="footer">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-heart active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-share"></i>
  </span>
</li>
```

```
<ul class='tools'>
<li>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
  <h2>test  </h2>
  <p>test test test</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i>test</p>
  <p> <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>test</p>
   <span class="footer">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-heart active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-share"></i>
   </span>
 </li>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hmmm... That puts every item into the same line.

Comment: So if I have 7 items in one list they are all in one line

Comment: that does not work, `display: inline-flex;` overwrites that even if `!important`

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/1rs634mz/1/ ] id=tools_1 use with display: inline-flex;
and 2nd id=tools_2 li float left

Comment: That looks good in your example but ( added it to the post) my `.wrapper` around the `ul` causes all the `display:inline-flex;` lists to squezze in one row no matter how many items are in this one list.

Comment: Every list should breake after the line inside the wrapper is filled. And if ther is a new list, it should start on a new line for sure.

Comment: Wrapper width u set max- width. Anyways you need 4 ul li  side by side i mean inline. Please try to update your html section like the pic you given . I will help you for sure

Comment: I'm writing in haml. It is actually pretty complicated so I simplified it for this post. Here is what you see in the (updated) image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui5jrcbu99hcn4q/rails%20issue.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Gugubaight I dnt know haml. but I understand the structure look at my [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/b58xsend/2/ ] html structure . Look slimier   too yours. but the image that you update and the I found just one issue that is "%h1 my tool " which takes a height and on 2nd ul before.

Comment: I fixed it, simply added: `h1 {clear: both;}` Thank you for helping me out, you gave me the idea of changing that! Edit your answer and I'll accept it :-)